# T-SQL with ORDER BY differences in stored procedure reveal GROUP BY issues

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, asp.net-web-api, sql-order-by

I've got a data problem seen by my public demo site:

http://cbmiweb.com/GmapsV3/opedemo3.aspx

The default `ORDER` appears OK but changing to `Order By Total#Awards` exposes the problem clearly yet I am stuck on how to fix it.

The web page exposes a link to the **raw data** returned (fires the stored procedure) where you can see the data problem:

http://cbmiweb.com/CBMI.WebAPIservice/api/markers/GetGrants/2

In short, why does `@Sort = 1` "group" Institution="BISHOP STATE COMMUNITY COLLEGE" properly but when using `@Sort = 2`, this entity is "interleaved" with other institutions with 8 awards?

Using SQL Server 2008, here is the stored procedure which orders the final result set 3 different ways (the problem is most noticeable with @Sort = 2) shown above:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[FLAS2_List_Awards_V1]
    -- EXECUTE dbo.FLAS2_List_Awards_V1 2
    (@Sort  int = 1   -- 1 = descending order on TotalAmount
                      -- 2 = descending order on TotalAwards
                      -- 3 = ascending order on Institution
    )
AS
    CREATE TABLE #TempMarkers
    (
        ID nchar(6) NOT NULL,
        Institution nvarchar(255) NOT NULL,
        Street nvarchar(255) NULL,
        City nvarchar(255) NULL,
        State nvarchar(255) NULL,
        Zip nvarchar(255) NULL,
        Latitude decimal(28, 18) NULL,
        Longitude decimal(28, 18) NULL,
        TotalAwards decimal(16, 0) NULL,
        TotalAmount decimal (16, 0) NULL
    )

    INSERT INTO #TempMarkers(ID, Institution, Street, City, State, Zip,
                             Latitude, Longitude, TotalAwards, TotalAmount)
        SELECT DISTINCT
            C.ID, C.InstitutionName, 
            NULL AS street, NULL AS city, NULL AS state, NULL AS zip,
            NULL As Latitude, NULL As Longitude,
            COUNT(DISTINCT o.GrantNumber) as TotalAwards,
            SUM(DISTINCT o.TotalObligatedAmount) as TotalAmount
        FROM 
            dbo.FLAS2_Schools2 C
        INNER JOIN 
            dbo.FLAS2_Grants o ON c.id = o.ID
        -- where o.ID in (100654,100724)
        GROUP BY
            C.ID, C.InstitutionName
            --,Z.Lat 
            -- ,Z.Long

    UPDATE #TempMarkers 
    SET Street = x.street,
        City = x.city,
        State = x.state,
        Zip = x.zip     
    FROM 
        dbo.FLAS2_Schools2 X  
    WHERE 
        X.ID = #TempMarkers.ID
        AND X.InstitutionName = #TempMarkers.Institution

    UPDATE #TempMarkers 
    SET Latitude = Z.lat,
        Longitude = Z.Long
    FROM dbo.ZipCodesPreferred Z                         
    WHERE Z.ZipCode = #TempMarkers.Zip

    --SELECT * FROM #TempMarkers
    IF @Sort = 1 
    BEGIN
        SELECT DISTINCT  
            Marker.ID, Marker.Institution, 
            Marker.Street, Marker.City, Marker.State, Marker.Zip,
            Marker.Latitude, Marker.Longitude,
            Marker.TotalAmount, Marker.TotalAwards,
            Award.GrantNumber as GrantNumber,
            Award.TotalObligatedAmount as GrantAmount
        FROM 
            #TempMarkers Marker     
        INNER JOIN 
            dbo.FLAS2_Grants Award ON Marker.ID = Award.ID
        ORDER BY
            Marker.TotalAmount DESC, GrantAmount DESC
        FOR XML AUTO, ROOT('root')
    END

    IF @Sort = 2 
    BEGIN
        SELECT 
            Marker.ID, Marker.Institution, 
            Marker.Street, Marker.City, Marker.State, Marker.Zip,
            Marker.Latitude, Marker.Longitude,
            Marker.TotalAmount, Marker.TotalAwards,
            Award.GrantNumber as GrantNumber,
            Award.TotalObligatedAmount as GrantAmount
        FROM 
            #TempMarkers Marker     
        INNER JOIN 
            dbo.FLAS2_Grants Award ON Marker.ID = Award.ID
        ORDER BY
            Marker.TotalAmount DESC, GrantAmount DESC
        FOR XML AUTO, ROOT('root')
    END

    IF @Sort = 3 
    BEGIN
        SELECT 
            Marker.ID, Marker.Institution, 
            Marker.Street, Marker.City, Marker.State, Marker.Zip,
            Marker.Latitude, Marker.Longitude,
            Marker.TotalAmount, Marker.TotalAwards,
            Award.GrantNumber as GrantNumber,
            Award.TotalObligatedAmount as GrantAmount
        FROM 
            #TempMarkers Marker     
        INNER JOIN 
            dbo.FLAS2_Grants Award ON Marker.ID = Award.ID
        ORDER BY
            Marker.Institution, GrantAmount DESC
        FOR XML AUTO, ROOT('root')
END
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I just needed to ponder it a bit more after a break...

The ORDER BY clause was insufficient. When the primary sort column is something like TotalAwards, there are clearly going to be some "ties" (i.e. multiple entities having the same count of awards). So it is necessary to sort secondarily on the name column to remove the "interleaving" effect.

Proper ORDER BY clause is as follows:

```
order by Marker.TotalAwards DESC, Marker.Institution, GrantAmount DESC
```

Comment: Do mark your answer as correct and please change the title so that others will find this easily when they search for it